# String out of range when generated in a loop

Tags: string, loops, range

When I write such code that generates a list of random strings 5 chars long, in a number of 7:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

void generate(string*, int);

int main()
{
    string* list = new string[7];
    generate(list, 7);
    return 0;
}

void generate(string* list, int a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            list[i][j] = rand() % 20 + 96;
        }
        list[i][5] = '\0';
    }
}
```

I get an error "string subscript out of range". Any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - The code uses the **operator[]** function to access nonexistent elements of an empty string.

Each element of the variable **list** is an empty C++ string object created by the **new string[]** statement.

Within the for loops, **list[i]** accesses an empty string and the following **operator[j]** function attempts to access an element of that string when it doesn't exist.

You can instead use the std::string functions **append()** or **operator+=** to add the random character values to the strings.